# Significance of >* in the url parameter of jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reload an element via jQuery and curious to know what is the difference between this

```
$("#elementID").load(location.href+" #elementID >*");
```

and this

```
$("#elementID").load(location.href+" #elementID");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` is the [direct child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and `*` means "any element".  So `#elementID > *"` means "all direct child elements of `#elementID`".

Basically, the `> *` prevents you from having multiple `#elementID` elements.

---

When you load using:

```
$("#elementID").load(location.href+" #elementID");
```

Then what you'll get is:

```
<div id="elementID">
    <div id="elementID">
        <p>Some Text<p>
        <span>More Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

So, we tell jQuery to grab all *child* elements and load those into the page:

```
$("#elementID").load(location.href+" #elementID > *");
```

Then what you'll get is:

```
<div id="elementID">
    <p>Some Text<p>
    <span>More Text</span>
</div>
```